# Infer constructor arguments from a list of constructed classes

Tags: typescript

Given the following code, I'd like to infer the union `type Bar = "quux" | "fubar"` (representing all the values passed to any  `bar` in the list of classes returned from `D`) from any given function in the shape of `D`. Is that possible?

```js
type ConstructorA = {foo: string}
class A {
    constructor({ foo }: ConstructorA) {
        // ...
    }
}

type ConstructorB = {foo: string, bar: string}
class B {
    constructor({ foo, bar }: ConstructorB) {
        // ...
    }
}

class C {
    constructor({ foo, bar }: ConstructorB) {
        // ...
    }
}

const D = () => ({
    A: new A({ foo: "baz" }),
    B: new B({ foo: "qux", bar: "quux" }),
    C: new C({ foo: "foobar", bar: "fubar" }),
});

// type Bar = "quux" | "fubar"
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EGEqI0AUzmp04T5DS4AAfHl8+pwsUJABW8lkrqo8BVcHVUjI8AhVEk8ANyddwFsEHk8BqiCNzfVWTEAFlEBJwFJZTAAArEMC2DToEaU6mk3P5jktD5jieQcEtvQ4AA8u5I++nc4gC8BGgGI1R6kBXmWx+kYGb-18D9wx9i78-ZhwiAA

Comment: Where would you like to use this type `Bar`?

Comment: In my actual use case I have a React component that takes a prop `bar` that may only be a `bar` that has been passed to any of the classes in `D`. This is some business logic that I'd like to enforce if possible

Comment: Right... I think a minimal reproducible example using JSX would be better here.

Comment: Added a link to a playground

Comment: [A little icky](https://tsplay.dev/NdrrkW)... I'll clean it up and explain it if it works for you?

Comment: That was fast, thanks! I think I get the gist of it even though I haven't done too much with conditional types / the `infer` keyword. Ideally I'd like a solution that does not need `B<any, infer U> | C<any, infer U> `, i.e. does not need to be adjusted anytime I add another class to `D`

Comment: Well, then I guess you could try something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7oonN), but it does require you to use an extra public field on every class which may or may not be ok with you.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved that by making the `ContructorB` and the classes that use it generic over `"bar"`, then use conditional type + `infer` to derive the `bar` union.

```
type ConstructorA = {foo: string}
class A {
    constructor({ foo }: ConstructorA) {
        // ...
    }
}

type ConstructorB<BBar extends string> = {foo: string, bar: BBar}
class B<BBar extends string> {
    constructor({ foo, bar }: ConstructorB<BBar>) {
        // ...
    }
}

class C<CBar extends string> {
    constructor({ foo, bar }: ConstructorB<CBar>) {
        // ...
    }
}

const D = () => ({
    A: new A({ foo: "baz" }),
    B: new B({ foo: "qux", bar: "quux" }),
    C: new C({ foo: "foobar", bar: "fubar" }),
});


type Bar = ReturnType<typeof D> extends {B: B<infer BBar>, C: C<infer CBar>} ? BBar | CBar : never;
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=100&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gMQMIF84BmUEIcA5FCgIYDGMZAsAFCiSxwBK1dhxpF3es2ZJUcbBAB2AZxhQArnWgBBOAF4MBCBABccWVGCSA5rmY0ANlWnS4q9MzhO4NKQcUxoACnSFtcXD0JGTkPFQBKDEdnGIB6WLgAOmTopzMmdJFkNGD3JSgAIQAeAoKqKDgUAA8YFEkAE1sDI2MAPnVNbT1mkwAaOAAjcr1S8vTLa1ti0Yrq2oamuRb2hyYY1xCFfJ8-CH6hisDxN1D86bKoVsjVmLiE5MTUgOZMpgmbcSLsC8qausb9EsTCsnhs8p4oDstHtBuUAkETlsIcVvuUrlE1rcnPEkilMWkXsI3ic4AARDpeSJqdo%20J7KPSSFAAdzsUK6cAAREMAF4cgLhXpPAoM5lwAps3ScgCO8iqHP2w2l8llfNwAqe2BFLOwEr0HOhB3lsKgeoI8kN-MFGXCAG4iVkxD8NFwYPIoJIACrZIqiFAQAhk9pzf62dDCsVFIwEFAVGatfqaz5RmPiC6tfAAfjFPwAPqm4SKAG4xu1MHFwAB6GftZYSAHFgMXJHAAAaklv9ACSZHqcAswAA1mhPHAABZUYtwKhweSSYBSBDZOD%20qcWCwIUdoFsHFtwQtUCzyFDSZg4zu2GDj%20CQGzAAYWFDV2uLx1wtTvpUquB5-Xm8ocokcQAK3kWQNyoeBOzgeopDIeAmSoSR4BHX0N2AWwIHkeABkQMdEPqB00AAWUQCRwCkOoYAABWIMBbA0dADj1GUvx-M1DXGEkSLIyBGSQvQcCKbiSF4yiaIgOj2g0HYDn5dQaSeIppDARDWl8WTcCKWJlNU5hwiAA)